# In Spring MVC 3 how can you map multiple urls with query parameters  ("/a" and "/b?xyz") to one handler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

"/b" has been already mapped to another handler. 
RequestMapping(value = {"/a","/b?xyz"}) does not seem to work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you change the way the other handler is mapped to include @RequestMapping(value="/b", params = "!xyz")   ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
@RequestMapping("/a")
public void yourMethodA() {
 // do the common controller logic
}

@RequestMapping(value="/b", params = "xyz")
public void yourMethodB() {
 yourMethodA(); // delegating the 1st mapped method
}
```

This way, you don't repeat yourself and you are able to define your mappings accurately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map query string parameters, you shouldn't do it in the `value` member of `RequestMapping`, but rather in the `params` member:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/a", "/b"}, params = "xyz")
public void yourMethod() {
}
```

Of course, this will only match `/a` if it also has the param xyz.

Comment: reply to "this will only match /a if it also has the param xyz", that is exactly my problem :(.

Comment: @Bobo: Your question is not very descriptive, and is lacking helpful code.  Perhaps you should consider editing your question and providing more information to allow us to better help you.